# Run systemd service with sudo rights

Tags: apache2, dotnet

I have a Raspberry PI (Ubuntu 20.04) that is running a Web UI with a button to turn on a relay (communicate with the Raspberry PI from the Web UI) so in order to do that, I need to run it with sudo rights. This is my service file

```
[Unit]
Description= My Web UI

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.dotnet/dotnet /var/www/My.Web.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-My.Web
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I put **/usr/bin/sudo** at the beginning of ExecStart is that all is needed?

Do I need **User=www-data**? I tried putting sudo in USER but got error: "Auth could not identify password for"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services are enabled and disabled with `sudo` and do not need to be contained within the service file. The way you've configured the file appears to be correct syntactically so, with this in mind, it should be possible to activate it like this:

```
sudo systemctl enable {name_of}.service
```

<sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{name_of}` with the actual `.service` file name.</sup>

If the service is going to run as `www-data`, then `User=www-data` is required.

So long as everything is good, you should be able to start the service:

```
sudo service {name_of} start
```

<sup>**Note:** Again, be sure to replace `{name_of}` with the name of the service. Note there is no `.service` here.</sup>

So long as everything is good, you can treat this as a regular service, checking its status with:

```
sudo service {name_of} status
```

Stopping it with:

```
sudo service {name_of} stop
```

And restarting it with:

```
sudo service {name_of} restart
```

<sup>**Note:** This is generally required after updating the .Net package to ensure the old cache is purged and the new files are correctly loaded.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the response. To clarify, will this give my dotnet app sudo permissions to perform the Raspberry Pi operations? Thats why I thought I had to do ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /home/ubuntu/.dotnet/dotnet /var/www/My.Web.dll. When I do this, I get error "  ubuntu dotnet-My.Web[4890]: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper"

Comment: This will have your service run as `www-data`. If you do not want your service to run as the Apache user, then you can remove the line to have it run as `root`.

Comment: I don't like how this answer uses `service` instead of `systemctl`.

Comment: @iBug if you're not a fan of `service`, then perhaps you could write an answer of your own that uses the `systemctl` syntax? There really is not much difference between one and the other for the purposes of this answer 

Comment: @DavidJS It doesn't make sense to use `/usr/bin/sudo` in the command line of a service definition... you can just tell systemd to launch your service as root (or as a different user the you configured with the appropriate groups/permissions/capabilities).

Comment: @GACy20 - So if I do this "sudo service gates.cardreaderweb start" is that good enough? What about User=sudo?